# meteor up Prepare Bundle: FAILED

Tags: docker, meteor, deployment, ubuntu-16.04, meteor-up

Meteor up returns this error after successful upload. What could be wrong to make right?

```
[xxx.xxx.xx.xx] x Prepare Bundle: FAILED

    -----------------------------------STDERR-----------------------------------
    Error response from daemon: No such container: myappsupload
    The command '/bin/sh -c cd  /built_app/programs/server &&     npm install --unsafe-perm' returned a non-zero code: 1
    Error response from daemon: No such container: myappsupload
    Error: failed to start containers: myappsupload
    -----------------------------------STDOUT-----------------------------------
    mnpm ERR! meteor-dev-bundle@0.0.0 install: `node npm-rebuild.js`
    npm ERR! Exit status 254
    npm ERR!
    npm ERR! Failed at the meteor-dev-bundle@0.0.0 install script 'node npm-rebuild.js'.
    npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
    npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the meteor-dev-bundle package,
    npm ERR! not with npm itself.
    npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
    npm ERR!     node npm-rebuild.js
    npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
    npm ERR!     npm bugs meteor-dev-bundle
    npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
    npm ERR!     npm owner ls meteor-dev-bundle
    npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

    npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
    npm ERR!     /built_app/programs/server/npm-debug.log

    ----------------------------------------------------------------------------

C:\Programs\contract\myappsupload\.deploy>
```

Comment: Where is the coming from `myappsupload`? Did you configure something

Comment: Sorry myappsupload is only a psuedo for schoolapps.

Comment: Any help. I have been on this deployment issue for more than 4 days. I have to upgrade the server to KVM today.

Comment: What happens when you run `docker ps` from the command prompt after this error?

Comment: Can you at least post the contents of your mup.js file, otherwise we have no clue as to why this might be happening

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Meteor-up terminates after running deploy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46198606/meteor-up-terminates-after-running-deploy)

Comment: This is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46198606/meteor-up-terminates-after-running-deploy - please do not add another question when it is just a continuation of an existing problem

Comment: I have upgraded to 2Gb Ram, 40Gb Rom, still the same error.

Comment: This looks like it is missing an [mcve], or is a dup of an existing question.