# Docker not naming images Meteorup

Tags: docker, containers, vps, meteor-up, ubuntu-16.10

I am trying to deploy an application to a server. I am using Meteorup for deployment. This deployment config on this post is what I use [Meteor-up terminates after running deploy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46198606/meteor-up-terminates-after-running-deploy][1]).

This is part of the questions I have raised and yet none have solved it https://github.com/zodern/meteor-up/issues/734[1]. After much troubleshooting, I ran `docker images`, it actually added names to the images of mongodb and abernix/meteord but for the one I want to deploy it did not. Why? Since containers are created from images definitely it will not see the container as there is no image to reference for creation.

See this:

```
root@hostname:~# docker images
REPOSITORY          TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
<none>              <none>              06f352515b0a        41 minutes ago      659MB
<none>              <none>              e29de6b55976        About an hour ago   659MB
abernix/meteord     base                7941fc48936e        2 months ago        520MB
mongo               3.4.1               0dffc7177b06        8 months ago        402MB
```

When I ran `docker ps` it showed that only `mongo` container was created:

```
root@christdoes:~# docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                        NAMES
2e7f21a50dfb        mongo:3.4.1         "/entrypoint.sh mo..."   2 hours ago         Up 2 hours          127.0.0.1:27017->27017/tcp   mongodb
```

How do I resolve this issue?